# CSS 3D navigation in opera not working

Tags: css, 3d, navigation

**Live example:**
http://www.script-tutorials.com/demos/298/index.html (move mouse on the blue bar on the top of page)

**My problem:**
This css 3d navigation menu (on the top) not work in Opera browser.
Why please? The css have this:

> -o-transition: -o-transform 0.5s ease;

**-o-** is not opera?

Comment: Vendor prefixes are not meant to be permanent.  When the implementation and/or specification is considered stable, prefixes are supposed to go away entirely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Opera does not require a vendor prefix for `transform`, the vendor prefix `-o-` is only needed for `transition` and `border-image`.

Try using the normal `transform` as the transition property, instead of `-o-transform`, but keep the `-o-transition: ...`

```css
-o-transition: transform 0.5s ease;
```